# The value for the useBean class attribute bean.LoginBean is invalid

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I am using simple JSP page to login with valid user name and password. As soon as I press a submit button, I am getting error

```
Nov 17, 2014 10:54:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /loginprocess.jsp(3,0) The value for the useBean class attribute bean.LoginBean is invalid.
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1231)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1178)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3442)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:231)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:327)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:326)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
```

I have a bean package which consists of following classes

- Connection provider - Mysql Connector
- Loginbean - Bean of email-id and password
- LoginDAO
- Provider

Code:

```
<%@page import="bean.LoginDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.LoginBean"/>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>

<%
    boolean status=LoginDao.validate(obj);

    if(status){
        out.println("You r successfully logged in");
        session.setAttribute("session","TRUE");
    }
    else
    {
        out.print("Sorry, email or password error");
    %>
    <jsp:include page="index.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <%
    }
%>
```

Comment: I'm not into JSP, but is the `%> <% ` in the middle of outer `<% %>` tag correct?

Comment: @AndrewT. the usage of the tags are correct he is having two scriptlets tags.